# Angular - ngpackagr - How to include custom files and dependencies like bootstrap / custom themes?

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-packagr

I'm building an Angular 5 component library with ng-packagr. The components preferably should work out of the box. So that you can install the library and everything will work fine. My problem: The library has some dependencies. I have to include bootstrap (+jquery) which I included in my angular-cli.json file for now. Furthermore I use custom themes which are stored in a seperate folder. I want them to be packaged by ng-packagr and if I install the library the dependencies should install with them, preferably there should be no other work to do for the user of the library. Is this possible? If so how?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

bump

Comment: Take a look to the similar question → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427555/how-can-i-make-a-theme-able-angular-material-npm-module